# Eye bones issue

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting, vertex-weights

So I was making a model for a game when I noticed that the eye bones I had added weren't working properly. If I rotate the eye bones, the eyeballs become flatter and moves further into the head. After about 2 turns the eyeballs turn into spheroids.

I had assigned the respective vertex groups to the eyeballs (weight:1.00). Attached is the screenshot of the eyeballs and bones. What am I doing wrong?
[image: eyeballs and bones]

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Either the eye bones are also weighted to another bone, inappropriately, or else they're inheriting non-uniform scale from something that probably shouldn't be scaled.

Comment: Thanks! It worked.